# Linux EAP-TLS Authentication

Tags: networking, wired, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to get EAP-TLS working on an Ubuntu Linux machine.  The system is controlled by Centrify and Centrify has pushed out a certificate, private key and chain file to the machine.  I am attempting to use the wpa_supplicant with the following configuration:

[wpa_supplicant.conf file is linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDkdC.png)

When we run the following command:

sudo -i wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -D wired -i eno1

We see the following sequence of messages repeated.  I am trying to validate that the private key doesn't have a password.  I am also going to try with key_mgmt set to WPA-EAP.  I can see the request come into ISE but ISE is recording the client is rejecting the authentication protocol which maybe the WPA-EAP will fix.  Has anyone gotten wpa_supplicant to work correctly?

Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
eno1: Associated with 01:80:c2:00:00:03
WMM AC: Missing IEs
eno1: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
eno1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
eno1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
OpenSSL: tls_connection_ca_cert - Failed to load root certificates error:0B084088:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:no certificate or crl found
OpenSSL: tls_load_ca_der - Failed load CA in DER format error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B06F00D:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:ASN1 lib
TLS: Failed to set TLS connection parameters
EAP-TLS: Failed to initialize SSL.
eno1: EAP: Failed to initialize EAP method: vendor 0 method 13 (TLS)
eno1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
eno1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
eno1: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
OpenSSL: tls_connection_ca_cert - Failed to load root certificates error:0B084088:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:no certificate or crl found
OpenSSL: tls_load_ca_der - Failed load CA in DER format error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_item_embed_d2i:nested asn1 error
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0B06F00D:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_file:ASN1 lib
TLS: Failed to set TLS connection parameters
EAP-TLS: Failed to initialize SSL.